# How to use DSA key pairs instead of RSA

Tags: ssh, rsa, dsa

For testing purposes, I would like to enable DSA authentication on my server (let's name it A).
If I remove all the key pairs located under `/etc/ssh`, both RSA and DSA key pairs are generated on sshd restart.

The consequence is that, if I try to open a SSH connection from a server B to this server A, the following message is displayed :

```
The authenticity of host '...' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Do you know a way to disable the RSA authentication so that my server B uses the DSA to authentify on server A ?

Comment: What versions of ssh client and ssh server are you using?

Comment: @AlexHolst Both servers use `OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010` with protocol SSH 2.

Comment: Are you quite sure you want to use DSA? The rest of the world has largely abandoned it, and for good reasons.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know. As I said, this is for testing purposes. I manage a Java application which connects interactively to remote network equipments. Most of those use RSA, but unfortunately we have figured out that a few of them still use DSA. Thus, for having my application be compatible with those equipments, I have to use DSA on one of my test equipments so that I can test my modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I remove all the key pairs located under `/etc/ssh`, both RSA and DSA key pairs are generated on `sshd` restart.

If you are using CentOS/RHEL/Fedora, we generate missing keys automatically, based on the content of file `/etc/sysconfig/sshd`, where you should define, if you don't want to generate some of the keys.

> Do you know a way to disable the RSA authentication so that my server B uses the DSA to authentify on server A ?

If you want your server to use only DSA keys, you should change your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add `HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key` (and remove the lines specifying the other keys if you have such).

Comment: Perfect. I used `ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key` to generate the DSA key manually and now it works as expected. Thank you.